# Cucumber class ignored classparh for local runs. All test runs

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, junit5, java-17

Test project environment:

- java 17
- junit5
- cucumber7
- maven 3.3.9

Runner class:

```
@Cucumber
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("project/uss/as/play/test/features/smoke/smoke_test.feature")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "project.uss.as.play.test")
public class RunnerTest {
}
```

```
src  
│
└───main
    │   
    ├───java
    │   │
    │   ├─── project.uss.as.play.test
    │        MyClass.java
    │
    test
    ├───java
    │   │
    │   ├─── project.uss.as.play.test
    │        AtPlayTest =.java
    │
    ├───resources
    │   │
    │   ├─── project.uss.as.play.test
              │
              ├─── features
                   smoke.smoke_test.feature
```

At local start from inteliji idea all test runs from `features` folder, despite the setting `@SelectClasspathResource("project/uss/as/play/test/features/smoke/smoke_test.feature")`.
I found that at startup generate folder's structure in `target`:
`target/test-classes/project/uss/as/play/test/features`  and runner class `RunnerTest`, and all features from `test/resources/project/uss/as/play/test/features/`. That means that test run from this temporary folder. If I delete some case or folder with cases, than this cases (features) not run. I have two question:

1. How I can startup specific features at local run in IDE?
2. Where I read documentation, where where is the mechanism tests run described.(I mean generated folder structure in `target`)

In old version runner class looked like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/features/smoke/smoke_test.feature",
        glue = "com.savkk.test"
)
public class RunnerTest {
}
```

And I can run specific features (e.g. smoke_test.feature).
Than I can't. Than all features runs.

Comment: Use the the latest version of Cucumber and replace the deprecated `@Cucumber` with `@Suite`. You can read docs here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine and use this as a reference https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: TY. It's help me. How I can close question, like ANSWERED without answer?)

Comment: There should be a delete button somewhere.

Comment: delete my question?

Comment: Yeah. It's Stackoverflow. Your questions seems to be based on a small mistake, so it won't be useful for other people, so there is no need to keep it around. Eventually, without answers, an automated process will delete it.

Comment: If you do want other people to know the solution, you could write an answer to your own question.

Comment: I understand) TY